not preview image in embed : its starboard custom command use on yagpdb bot
I am using YAGPDB discord bot (custom command section) and I need to display a preview of images or videos in an embed when a message is starred. Below is the script I am currently using:
embed created but preview is not working. if you help me to fix this issue it will help me lot. thanks in advance.
{{/\* CONFIGURATION VALUES START */}}
{{ $starEmoji := "⭐" }} {{/* Star emoji name */}}
{{ $starLimit := 1 }} {{/* Reactions needed for message to be put on starboard */}}
{{ $starboard := 736324263107231885 }} {{/* ID of starboard channel */}}
{{/* CONFIGURATION VALUES END \*/}}

{{ $linkRegex := `https?:\/\/(?:\w+\.)?[\w-]+\.[\w]{2,3}(?:\/[\w-_.]+)+(?:\?(?:[\w-]+=[\w-]+&?)+)?\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|mp4|mpeg|avi|mov|wmv|flv|mkv|webm)` }}

{{ $count := 1 }}
{{ range .ReactionMessage.Reactions }}
{{ if and (eq .Emoji.Name $starEmoji) (ge .Count $starLimit) }}
{{ $count = .Count }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}

{{ $starboardMessage := 0 }}
{{ $thisID := .ReactionMessage.ID }}
{{ with (dbGet 0 "starboardMessages").Value }}
{{ $idRegex := printf `%d:(\d+)` $thisID }}
{{ with reFindAllSubmatches $idRegex . }} {{ $starboardMessage = index . 0 1 }} {{ end }}
{{ if not (getMessage $starboard $starboardMessage) }}
{{ $starboardMessage = 0 }}
{{ dbSet 0 "starboardMessages" (reReplace $idRegex . "") }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}

{{ if and $count (or .ReactionMessage.Content .ReactionMessage.Attachments) (eq .Reaction.Emoji.Name $starEmoji) }}
{{ $emoji := "" }}
{{ if lt $count 5 }} {{ $emoji = "⭐" }}
{{ else if lt $count 10 }} {{ $emoji = "" }}
{{ else if lt $count 15 }} {{ $emoji = "✨" }}
{{ else if lt $count 20 }} {{ $emoji = "" }}
{{ else if lt $count 30 }} {{ $emoji = "" }}
{{ else if lt $count 40 }} {{ $emoji = "" }}
{{ else if lt $count 50 }} {{ $eomji = "☄️" }}
{{ end }}
{{ $embed := sdict
"color" 0xFFAC33
"fields" (cslice
(sdict "name" "Author" "value" .ReactionMessage.Author.Mention "inline" true)
(sdict "name" "Channel" "value" (printf "\<#%d\>" .Channel.ID) "inline" true)
)
"timestamp" .ReactionMessage.Timestamp
"thumbnail" (sdict "url" (.ReactionMessage.Author.AvatarURL "1024"))
"footer" (sdict "text" (printf "%s %d | %d" $emoji $count .ReactionMessage.ID))
}}
{{ with .ReactionMessage.Content }}
{{ with reFind $linkRegex . }} {{ $embed.Set "image" (sdict "url" .) }} {{ end }}
{{ $content := . }}
{{ if gt (len .) 1000 }} {{ $content = slice . 0 1000 | printf "%s..." }} {{ end }}
{{ $embed.Set "fields" ($embed.fields.Append (sdict "name" "Message" "value" $content)) }}
{{ end }}
{{ with .ReactionMessage.Attachments }}
{{ $attachment := (index . 0).URL }}
{{ if reFind `\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|mp4|mpeg|avi|mov|wmv|flv|mkv|webm)$` $attachment }}
{{ $embed.Set "image" (sdict "url" $attachment) }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
{{ $embed.Set "fields" ($embed.fields.Append (sdict
"name" "Message"
"value" (printf "[View Original Post](https://discordapp.com/channels/%25d/%25d/%25d)" .Guild.ID .Channel.ID .ReactionMessage.ID)))
}}
{{ with $starboardMessage }}
{{ editMessage $starboard . (cembed $embed) }}
{{ else }}
{{ $ret := sendMessageRetID $starboard (cembed $embed) }}
{{ dbSet 0 "starboardMessages" (printf
"%s\\n%d:%d"
(or (dbGet 0 "starboardMessages").Value "")
.ReactionMessage.ID $ret
) }}
{{addMessageReactions $starboard $ret "" ""}}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}```


What do you mean by "not working"? Is the image just not being displayed or does the URL not load? If it doesn't load, maybe check the URL of the preview image/video?

yes, preview not showing of image and videos.
